# Как настроить Django-presence

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

В своем Django-проекте я хочу сделать онлайн статус. Решил это делать с помощью django-channels-presence, в интернете мало информации на эту тему, только документация. Почитал ее, вроде настроил Consumer, routing.py, asgi.py, но выдает ошибку.

> Traceback ...
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rooms'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> Traceback ...
>
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'rooms'.
> Check that 'channels_presence.apps.RoomsConfig.name' is correct.

Comment: я реализовал аналогичный функционал при помощи middleware функции

Comment: я бы хотел с помощью websocket, чтобы каждые 30 секунд обновлялся статус, а не только при обновлении страницы